# How to write following query in CDbCriteria (yii)?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
$query="select U.MUID,U.UID,U.PWD,U.UNAME,U.EMAILID,U.GROUPID,U.TRANSDATE,U.ACTIVEYN,
            G.GRP_DESC,G.FACTORY_SETTING from mas_users U
            inner join user_group G on U.GROUPID=G.GROUPID
            where U.ACTIVEYN=1 and U.GROUPID  <> 6 AND MUID <>1729 and MUID <>1727 and U.GROUPID <> 100000 order by U.GROUPID";
```

Please help me to write the query as CDBcrieteria in yii

Answer (score 1):

You first should read all the content present in yii study guide which is very helpful to you during development here itself i will write the solution but it will diminish your learning ability instead of that i request you to read this content from yii study guide.

suggestion : learn about scopes clearly.

please click the given link

[relational AR](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this

[this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10185-using-relations-and-conditions/)

this is the best way of extarting data from table joins

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution helps you:

```
    $array = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('U.MUID,U.UID,U.PWD,U.UNAME,U.EMAILID,U.GROUPID,U.TRANSDATE,U.ACTIVEYN, G.GRP_DESC,G.FACTORY_SETTING from mas_users U')
        ->from('mas_users U')
        ->join('user_group G','U.GROUPID=G.GROUPID')
        ->compare('U.ACTIVEYN=:ain')
        ->andWhere('U.GROUPID  <>:gid')
        ->addNotInCondition('MUID', array(1729,1727))
        ->addNotInCondition('U.GROUPID', array(6,100000))
        ->order('U.GROUPID')
        ->bindValue(':ain',1,PDO::PARAM_INT)
        ->bindValue(':gid',6,PDO::PARAM_INT)
        ->queryAll();
```